# change detection angular 2 model's property

Tags: angular, reactivex

I need to call a JQuery function each time if my model's **propery** got changed.

```
person = {firstName:firstName, lastName:lastName}
```

as an example If I changed the **firstName** property of person object, every time I need to trigger a function. Actually I need a something like subscription to this object's property.

How is it possible?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer to see if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for the `DoCheck` ([link to docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#docheck)) life cycle hook. It is an event that will be triggered after every completed round of change detection. Keep in mind though that it will potentially be triggered a lot, and doing heavy operations in that hook could have a major negative impact on performance.

Here is an example that looks for changes on the `person.firstName` property, and logs it to the console if changes are found:

```
import { Component, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="person.firstName">`,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements DoCheck {
  person = { firstName: 'Donald', lastName: 'Duck' };
  oldFirstName: string;

  ngDoCheck() {
    if (this.person.firstName !== this.oldFirstName) {
      console.log(`Change first name from "${this.oldFirstName}" to "${this.person.firstName}"`);
      this.oldFirstName = this.person.firstName;
    }
  }
}
```